# getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) throwing exception on mobile data

Tags: android, exception, error-handling

I have a utility method that checks for a wifi connection and returns the SSID. It works fine when the mobile is on a Wifi connection but it fails when i am on a mobile data connection. Even using a try catch block within the utility does not catch the exception. Nothing gets executed from the `getSystemService` line..verified using debug logs. The exact code is:

```
public static String getCurrentSsid(Context context) {

    String ssid = null;
    NetworkInfo networkInfo;
    ConnectivityManager connManager;

    try {
        connManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        networkInfo = connManager
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }

    if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        final WifiInfo connectionInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
        if (connectionInfo != null) {
            ssid = connectionInfo.getSSID();
        }
    }
    return ssid;
}
```

The logcat only shows errors for the Async task in which i am calling this utility. Any idea where i am going wrong?

```
11-30 21:42:38.723: W/dalvikvm(21207): threadid=14: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4165e2a0)
11-30 21:42:38.733: E/AndroidRuntime(21207): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
11-30 21:42:38.733: E/AndroidRuntime(21207): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-30 21:42:38.733: E/AndroidRuntime(21207):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
11-30 21:42:38.733: E/AndroidRuntime(21207):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
11-30 21:42:38.733: E/AndroidRuntime(21207):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
11-30 21:42:38.733: E/AndroidRuntime(21207):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
11-30 21:42:38.733: E/AndroidRuntime(21207):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-30 21:42:38.733: E/AndroidRuntime(21207):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
11-30 21:42:38.733: E/AndroidRuntime(21207):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
11-30 21:42:38.733: E/AndroidRuntime(21207):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
11-30 21:42:38.733: E/AndroidRuntime(21207):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
11-30 21:42:38.733: E/AndroidRuntime(21207): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-30 21:42:38.733: E/AndroidRuntime(21207):    at com.example.slapp.PhoneContactsListFragment$setInviteVisibilityAsync.doInBackground(PhoneContactsListFragment.java:1069)
11-30 21:42:38.733: E/AndroidRuntime(21207):    at com.example.slapp.PhoneContactsListFragment$setInviteVisibilityAsync.doInBackground(PhoneContactsListFragment.java:1)
11-30 21:42:38.733: E/AndroidRuntime(21207):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
11-30 21:42:38.733: E/AndroidRuntime(21207):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-30 21:42:38.733: E/AndroidRuntime(21207):    ... 5 more
```

Comment: @Hamad thanks for formatting the logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the posted code.

The problem was that, in case the mobile is on mobile data mode, the function returns a null back to my Async Task. And i did not check for a null condition when processing the return value there. So all i had to do was add a null check before the actual check, as below :

```
String ssid = getCurrentSsid(Context);
if (ssid != null && ssid.equals("xyz")) { //do something}
```